# how to access dynamically created list in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a unordered list of links, which are dynamically created by Ajax, and for each link i want to add click function to it, but it won't work, please help!

here is my code:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="sidebar">
  <li>
      <h2> list </h2>
      <ul id="list"></ul>
  </li>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
//to create links
var str = '';
$.each(json.opts, function(i, opt) {
  var id = opt + '-list';
  str += '<li><a href="#" id='+ id +'>' + opt + '</a></li>';   //link
}
$("#list").html(str);

...
//to add click function to each links, this won't work
$("#list li").each(function (i) {
   alert(i + " : " + $(this).text());
});
```

Comment: You know that your HTML is not valid? `li` elements must be enclosed by `ul` or `ol`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) instead of [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$("#list li").click(function (i) {
   alert(i + " : " + $(this).text());
});
```

And if you call this function, the elements must already be inserted. Otherwise you have to use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
$("#list li").live('click', function (i) {
   alert(i + " : " + $(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Description: Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now or in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I've been fighting this all day!

[.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is what I needed.

I had dynamically created slide number links that weren't responding to .click()