# This code displays an number of li inside an ol

Tags: c#, javascript, html, razor

This is what I should have posted in the first place.

This code displays an number of li inside an ol. Each li is represented on the page with a number(1 thru ...). Is there any way that I can access the current li number value with HTML, C#, Razor or JavaScript so that I can display it myself elsewhere on the page?

```
<div id="movieslist">
<ol>
    @foreach(var row in data)
    {
        <li>
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td width="950px" valign="baseline">@row.Name, @row.ReleaseYear, @row.Genre</td>
                <td align="right" width="50px">
                    @{displayCount++;@displayCount;}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select style="background-color:ThreeDFace">
                        <option>Choose Action</option>
                        <option onclick="window.location='dataMovies.cshtml?id=@row.id'">Google it</option>
                        <option onclick="window.location='EditMovie.cshtml?id=@row.id'">Edit Movie</option>
                        <option onclick="window.location='DeleteMovie.cshtml?id=@row.id'">Delete Movie</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </li>
    }
</ol>
```

Comment: I don't see the number in the `li`. Where is it?

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: The `ol` element, by default, styles its children to be numbered. The question asks how to get the number so it can be manually added into the HTML as well.

Comment: maybe you can add a coundter and append it to `li` id

Comment: @icktoofay: Ah, this number is meant. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean the numbering that is automatically allied by the browser when `ol` or Ordered List is used.

With JQuery you could use [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

In CSS3 you can use the `nth-child` pseudo-selector to style specific elements:-
http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display it yourself, use ul and a counter. However, you can slightly modify the automatically displayed numbers as well.

Comment: Further to erenon's point on styling - here is a reference on the options http://htmlhelp.com/reference/css/classification/list-style-type.html

Comment: I am using a counter called displatCounter but I would prefer to access the automatically generated number directly if posible.

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466836/how-to-access-dynamically-created-list-in-jquery) will help you to achieve this.